# Deformation shaders with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0, shader, distortion

I develop a 2D game using OpenGL ES 2.0. I want to have simple deformation effects, e.g. a water drop making a distortion of whats behind it.

More advanced example in 3D : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24TXpqa9jG0

How would I do that with vertex or fragment shaders ?

Thanks

Comment: "I want to have simple deformation effects" That is *not* a simple effect. And they're called "fragment shaders."

Comment: Simple compared to the yt video, it would be in the "simplest" case, in 2D etc.

Comment: Isn't there an example in the Rendermonkey Shaders, as far as I remember?

Comment: Since you show a video from Imagination Technologies, why don't you have a look at their sdk? You can download it after - free - registration : http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-sdk.asp